# Remove HTML entities and their content

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I have a snippet of html extracted by using `Document doc =jsoup.connect(someUrl).get()` and `Elements body=doc.select("div.chapter")`

```
String myHtml = "
<div class="chapter">
  <h1>Hello this is my example</h1>
  <p>This is paragraph one</p>
  <p>This is paragraph two <sup class="num">Nuisance 1</sup><span class="notes">Nuisance 2</span></p>
  <p>This is paragraph three</p>
</div>"
```

I want to remove `<sup> </sup>` and `<span> <\span>` their content with JSOUP. I have read that using regex syntax is a bad idea. And most of examples and answers address this question to remove the tag and keep the content. What I would like to get is:

```
String newHtml = "
<div class="chapter">
  <h1>Hello this is my example</h1>
  <p>This is paragraph one</p>
  <p>This is paragraph two</p>
  <p>This is paragraph three</p>
</div>"
```

I have used JSOUP with no satisfactory results (it keeps the SUP and SPAN entity/tag.).

Comment: `not` removes elements from the selection return that aren't specified in the query. It doesn't go *in* to each element.

Comment: please show us some effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read more (way more!) and trying different options, I have adapted a solution to my own case:

```
doc.getElementsByClass("notes").remove();
doc.getElementsByClass("num").remove(); 
Elements newElement = doc.select("div.chapter");
String newHtml=newElement.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using [`remove`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#remove%28%29) after [`select`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29)ing the `sup` elements:

```
doc.select("div > sup").remove();
```

There I've used a child combinator, which works for your specific example. If they're within child elements of the `div`, you'll have to adjust the selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
body.select("p > sup.num, p > span.notes").remove();
System.out.println(body.html());
```

should be perfect in your case.